# Application Cache Re-downloads on every visit (FF 27/30, Apache2)

Tags: apache, firefox, html5-appcache

My firefox refuses to update its appcache cache, even after calling the application's swapCache() or reloading the page.  I've validated the manifest, and it's known good.  I found the following article, but the responses were brief, and I found them unclear (see link below).  Interestingly, however possibly unrelated, it appears that FF and chrome are firing a different number of 'progress' events.

What would cause this?  What additional info may I provide?

Thank you

[HTML 5 Appcache works in safari/opera/chrome but not firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443311/html-5-appcache-works-in-safari-opera-chrome-but-not-firefox/11632911#11632911)

Answer (score 0):

This behavior occurs when the page referencing `yourManifestFile.appcache` is visited, and  `yourManifestFile.appcache` explicitly references itself in the `CACHE:` section